# vimeo video search in codeigniter

Tags: php, search, codeigniter-3, vimeo-api

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Class 'phpVimeo' not found
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\amrt\application\controllers\Vimeosearch.php
>
> Line Number: 21

Hi guys i have a problem for vimeo video search application.i use helper file from github https://github.com/mpmont/video_helper

I do not know how to use the code to search video please any one can help me??

My controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Vimeosearch extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('vimeosearch');
}

function vimeosearch()
{
    $query= $this->input->post('q');
    $key = "[MYKEY]";
    $secret = "[MYSECRET]";
    $limit = 12;
    $vimeo = new phpVimeo($key, $secret);
    $response = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.search', array('per_page' => $limit, 'query' => $query, 'sort' => 'relevant'));
    $jarray = array();
    foreach($response->videos->video as $v){
      $videoinfo = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getInfo', array('video_id' => $v->id));

      $jarray[] = array(
      "thumbnail" => $videoinfo->video[0]->thumbnails->thumbnail[1]->_content,
      "url" => $videoinfo->video[0]->urls->url[0]->_content,
      "title" => $videoinfo->video[0]->title,
      "username" => $videoinfo->video[0]->owner->display_name,
      "userurl" => $videoinfo->video[0]->owner->profileurl,
      "userpic" => $videoinfo->video[0]->owner->portraits->portrait[0]->_content
      );
    }

    print_r(str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($jarray)));
    die();

}
}
```

My view

```
<body>
<div id="w">
    <div id="top" class="clearfix">
        <h2>Vimeo Instant Search</h2>
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="sbox" tabindex="1" placeholder="Search videos...">
    </div>

    <div id="results" class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var s = $("#s"); // search input field
  var c = $("#results"); // results container
  var t; // timer 

  $("#s").keydown(function(e){

    clearTimeout(t);
    if (!args) { var args = []; }

    if (e.which === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) {
        // allow the user to ctrl+a or cmd+a to select text
        // without calling a new search function
    } else {
            t = setTimeout(function(){ vimeoSearch() }, 400);       
        }
    });

  function vimeoSearch() {
  c.empty();
  var q = s.val();

  // c.html('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="loading..." id="loader">');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url();?>/Vimeosearch/vimeosearch',
    data: "q="+q,
    success: function(data){

      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        var code = '<div class="v"> <span class="details"><img src="'+data[i].userpic+'" class="userpic"> <h3>'+data[i].title+'</h3> <span class="user">uploaded by <a href="'+data[i].userurl+'" target="_blank">'+data[i].username+'</a></span></span> <a href="'+data[i].url+'" target="_blank" class="wrapping"><img src="'+data[i].thumbnail+'" alt="'+data[i].title+' video thumbnail" class="thumbnail"></a> </div>';

        $("#loader").remove();
        c.append(code);
      }); // end each loop
    },
    error: function(xhr, type, exception) { 
      c.html("Vimeo Error: " + type); 
    }}); // end ajax call
} // end vimeoSearch() function
});
</script>
```

Comment: There is a reason `$secret` is called `$secret`. Not sure how relevant this is, but personally I would not post that data online. Might want to change the key and secret.

Comment: any one can help me. please

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the url you posted? Did you load the video helper?

Comment: https://github.com/sekati/codeigniter-vimeo-helper/blob/9b2223d251a3f310c606ea52314917054f467047/helpers/vimeo_helper.php

Comment: i got helper for this site,the site not have any instruction

Comment: https://github.com/sekati/codeigniter-vimeo-helper is the package home page with installation instructions. There's a totally different package url in your post. When you have decided which package you use please edit your post to reflect the changes so other users don't have to wade through comments to find out what package you are using. Follow the installation and usage instructions for the package you're using and come back when you encounter any errors.

Comment: that also not give me the exact result.  please help.);-

Comment: i use other code in php. that display empty array.